# javascript regex to extract paths from config.php string

Tags: javascript, php, regex, gulp

i like to minify all js-files from a config.php by gulp.

```
//config.php
c::set('myvar', true);

c::set('styles', [
  'test1.css',
  'test2.css'
]);

c::set('scripts', array(
  'node_modules/abc.min.js',
  'node_modules/def.js',
  'assets/js/xyz.js' 
));
```

i read the file by fs.readFile to a string. so far so good.
unfortunately i can't find the correct regex/match to get only the paths between:

c::set('scripts', array(

and

));

anybody knows the right regex?
i am regex newbie.
tnx

#### Update

With the regex from @Ken following the working solution:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    fs = require("fs"),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var jsfromconfigphp = [];

gulp.task('get-js-by-config-php', function(done) {
  const regex = /\s+(\'[\w\/\.]+\.js\')/gi;
  let m;
  fs.readFile('site/config/config.php', {encoding: 'utf-8', flag: 'rs'}, function(e, data) {
    if (e) {
      return console.log(e);
    }
    while ((m = regex.exec(data)) !== null) {
      // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
      if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
      }
      // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
      m.forEach((match, index) => {
        if(index === 1) {
          console.log(`Found match, group ${index}: ${match}`);
          jsfromconfigphp.push(match.slice(1, -1));
        }
      });
    }
    done();
  });
});

// wait for get-js-by-config-php is done
gulp.task('build-js', ['get-js-by-config-php'], function() {
  return gulp.src(jsfromconfigphp)
  .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
  .pipe(uglify({
    compress: {
      drop_console: true
    }
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'));
});
```

Comment: something like `fileContent.match(/c::set\((['"])scripts\1,\s*array\(([^)]*)/)[2]`?

Comment: @Thomas tnx, but TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null

Comment: updated my question with the total solution and the regex from @Ken H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet (with help from regex101.com) outputs the strings - does it meet your needs?

```js
const regex = /\s+(\'[\w\/]+\.js\')/gi;
const str = `c::set('myvar', true);

c::set('styles', [
  'test1.css',
  'test2.css'
]);

c::set('scripts', array(
  'node_modules/abc.js',
  'assets/js/xyz.js' 
));`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: I have updated the above config.php-example with more settings than only the js-part. could you explain, how to reduce the output to the script-part?

Comment: and why i get the same match in group 0 and in group 1. tnx

Comment: @dennisbaum - it's not exactly the same match. The match for the entire line (the "group 0") has the whitespaces, while the match for the parenthesized part of the expression ("group 1") just has the quoted string.  I'm not 100% clear on what you need, but it is a way to get either line by line or just the quoted filename for each line, and output it in a way that suits your needs. I hope that it helps you in some way.

Comment: I just noticed your other edit - it should be simple to add the `js` to the expression - I'll edit the post.

Comment: Tnx Ken, that works, but after i update the config.php again and for example add a 'node_modules/abc.min.js'. unfortunately that did not match... because of the '.min.js'. how to get also the .min?

Comment: Could try adding a `\.` inside the square brackets and see if that works? I'm on mobile now so let me know if you try it. I'll check later.

Comment: That works!  I will update my question with the complete code.  Tnx Ken!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way of achieving the same thing

```
var path = "c::set('scripts', array('node_modules/abc.js','assets/js/xyz.js'));";
path = path.replace("c::set('scripts', array(",'')
path = path.replace('));','')
path.replace(/["']/g, "").split(',')
```

Comment: tnx, but there are a lot more settings in the config.php, so i think replacing the following '));' is a problem. i have updated the code above.